# How to fix 'Boot complete not called on phone but on working on a emulator'

Tags: android

I tried to get my app started when the phone started.
It works perfectly on my emulator (5.4 FWVGA API 27) But on my Huawei p30 pro it's not working.

On the emulator it starts and returns the Log.e but on the phone the app is not starting in the background and also not returning the Log.e

For me it is no problem if it is only a Huawei issue but it makes me worried it wont work on other phones neither.

I followed some tutorials on the internet but nothing seems to work.
I tried disabling power saving for my app but didn't work neither.
Adding extra Log.e but they are never called.
Force close the app and reboot but the app stays closed.
Totally remove the app and reinstall. No effect.

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Receiver:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".service.BootDeviceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BootDeviceReceiver:

```
public class BootDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("AppTest ", "1");
    }
}
```

I would like that it starts to output something.
I'm aware there are already multiple topics about it but none of the few I found helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOOT_COMPLETED is not sent to the application unless the user launches your application first, after Android version 3.1", please read these lines (from official docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)

FURTHERMORE, UNTIL NOW (Android Oreo 8.0), when Android limits registering implicit broadcasts at Manifest (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts), several broadcasts are still currently exempted from these limitations. And BOOT_COMPLETED is the first one they mention ! (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html)

By the way, you can try Once

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <!--For HTC devices-->
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```